# Android watch as Bluetooth Central mode

Tags: android, watch

I am looking for a Android watch which can work as Bluetooth Central mode.
I want to connect a "peripheral" device directly with the watch device.

[watch]----BLE----[a peripheral device]

Can we find the watch as android central ?

Please advice me...

Kazu